# Audio duration in laravel from HLS src path

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel project, and a bulk amount of audio tracks are updated in the database with the time 00:00:00 as duration and generated HLS URL.
Now I have to write the script for getting audio duration via using the HLS path.

Is any possibility to achieve the same in Laravel? Any reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution,

I added a test template path to iterate the video and audio tag
I took the id and URL from the model file

```
$albumModel = $this->videos->selectRaw('videos.id , videos.video_url')->where('is_active', 1)->paginate(50)->toArray();
```

Then looped in the template file

```
<video width="100" height="100" id="{{ 'myAudio' + audio.id }}" controls>
        <source [src]="audio.video_url" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      {{ myFunction(audio.id) }}
```

Added the function in the javascript file to find the duration and console the update query log,

```
 myFunction = (id) => {
    
    var  audioCurrentTime = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myAudio' + id));
    var e = audioCurrentTime.duration;
    var h = Math.floor(e / 3600).toString().padStart(2,'0');
    var m = Math.floor(e % 3600 / 60).toString().padStart(2,'0');
    var s = Math.floor(e % 60).toString().padStart(2,'0');

    var dttr =  h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    console.log("UPDATE `videos` SET `video_duration` = '" + dttr + "'  WHERE `videos`.`id` = " + id + ";")
  }
```

Then copied the update query from the console log and run in the MySQL server.
By the way I solved my issue.